# Assembly.GetExportedTypes vs GetTypes

Tags: c#, .net

What does Assembly.GetExportedTypes() do? How is it different from Assembly.GetTypes()

Can you explain with example?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

GetExportedTypes() does not include protected/private/internal types. As per the question linked in Alexander's question below, internal types are not included even if would be visible to an assembly via InternalsVisibleToAttribute.

GetTypes() includes all types.

Comment: It is particularly confusing that nested `protected` types, and nested `protected internal` types, whose declaring types are public, are not returned. An example with [`TypeConverter+SimplePropertyDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.simplepropertydescriptor.aspx): `class MyClass : System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter { static void Main() { var exported = typeof(SimplePropertyDescriptor); Console.WriteLine(exported.IsVisible) /* writes False */; } }`

Answer (score 8):

`GetExportedTypes()` returns only types which are visible outside the assembly in question. "Visible" means public types and public types nested within other public types.

Comment: so you mean all public type are returned when GetExportedTypes() is used? What does GetTypes() do then?

Answer (score 3):

Little remark about `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384975/are-internal-types-visible-from-assembly-getexportedtypes).

Even if the call is made by an assembly with an `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute, `GetExportedTypes()` won't return `internal` types.

So, `GetExportedTypes()` returns only `public` types.