# Are internal types visible from Assembly.GetExportedTypes()?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, types, assemblies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assembly.GetExportedTypes vs GetTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/537548/assembly-getexportedtypes-vs-gettypes)

Are internal types visible when a call is made to `Assembly.GetExportedTypes()`?  If not, then does the call being made from an assembly with an `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` change the behavior?

Comment: Duplicate of [Assembly.GetExportedTypes vs GetTypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/537548/assembly-getexportedtypes-vs-gettypes)

Comment: @Si, @Richard Hein, @Jon, @adrianbanks, I updated the question.  It is no longer a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetTypes` returns all the types in the assembly while `GetExportedTypes` returns only the types marked as public, i.e.:

```
public class A
```

would be returned by both methods

```
class B
```

would only be returned by `GetExportedTypes`

Comment: so internal types are not visible?  what if the call is made by an assembly with an `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute?